# eDismax problem in SolR. Different behavior with dismax and edismax

Tags: java, solr, solrj

When I try to do a search like this :

```
q=context_text:"phone"+OR+description:"phone"+OR+full_text:"phone"&sort=score+desc&fl=*+score&qf=context_text^1+full_text^2+description^1&defType=dismax&rows=50&start=0
```

whit "**dismax**" my result score change if i change weight of filed
For example if i change

```
qf=context_text^1+full_text^2+description^1
```

in

```
qf=context_text^1+full_text^5+description^1
```

the score change. But if I use "**edismax**" (defType=edismax) the score of result is the same . the weight is not considered in the parameter "**qf**"

did I do something wrong?

Comment: I would add "debug=true" to your query and look at the output of the `parsedquery` (and `parsedqueryString`) under the `debug` node in the response. I suspect Solr might be parsing your query different and, if so, the `parsedquery` should show what is the difference.